# Trying to plot a bar chart in R with "character" on x axis and "factors" on y axis

Tags: r, character, bar-chart, numeric

Degrees:  ME, BE, EMPS, NAME, EIM, EC, MA, MH, OE, RC, CFS, AS

Income: 73926, 97410, 74179, 75635, 78866, 54000, 44800, 45000, 46300, 46400, 46500, 47000

structure(list(Degree = c("ME", "BE", "EMPS", "NAME", "EIM",
"Ec", "MA", "MH", "OE", "RC", "CFS", "AS"), Income = c(73926,
97410, 74179, 75635, 78866, 54000, 44800, 45000, 46300, 46400,
46500, 47000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-12L))

'''
barplot(data$Degrees, data$Income)
'''

Newbie to R here. I am trying to replicate the bar chart below, but in R. Really struggling with this as all attempts end with the error 'argument is not numeric or logical'. Unsure what to do next and any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code youre trying to run ?

Comment: It's much easier to help if you share a little bit of code and a little bit of data - please share both as text so we can use them, not as pictures.

Comment: Also, just an FYI, `factor` is a categorical variable, usually words where there are a small number of possibilities, `"low", "medium", "high"`, for example.  `character` data in plots is also treated as categorical. In your picture, you have a numbers on the y-axis, so they should be class `numeric` or `integer`, not `factor`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I have added the data which originally was in excel. Most of the research I have found online has left me clueless but the basic code that I am trying to make work is barplot(data$Degrees, data$Income), but comes with the error message of not numeric or logical.

Comment: @LuccaNielsen I am trying to use barplot(data$Degrees, data$Income). However, I am aware that this is a basic command I am unable to make it work and don't know what I should be using as obviously my x-axis is in character form.

Comment: It sounds like you might have some problems with the class of your data. Would you share `dput(data)`? This will make a copy/pasteable version of your data including the class and structure information.

Comment: @GregorThomas structure(list(Degree = c("ME", "BE", "EMPS", "NAME", "EIM", 
"Ec", "MA", "MH", "OE", "RC", "CFS", "AS"), Income = c(73926, 
97410, 74179, 75635, 78866, 54000, 44800, 45000, 46300, 46400, 
46500, 47000)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `ggplot2` package information

Tryed to create the code strucutre so you can edit some characteristc like texts size and etc:

```
ggplot(df)+
        geom_col(aes(x = Degree, 
                     y = Income),
                 fill = "blue",
                 width = 0.7)+
        theme_classic() +
        ggtitle("Graph title",
                subtitle = "Subtitle")+
        labs(x = "X axis title",
             y = "Y axis title")+
        theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 15, face = "bold"),
              axis.text = element_text(size = 10),
              plot.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
              plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 15, hjust= 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: You can use `geom_col` where `stat = "identity"` is the default.

Answer (score 1):

You might also try:

```
barplot( df$Income ~ df$Degree, col = "blue")
```

[image]

I wasn't sure how to do this (I mostly use ggplot2, not base R plots), but here's what I did to figure it out, in case it helps for any future endevours.

1. I selected the word `barplot` in the code and clicked F1 to get the help for the function. You can also type `?barplot` in the console.
2. R help files have a certain format that might take some getting used to. The "Usage" section on the top notes the arguments it takes. The "Examples" section at the bottom typically shows the normal way(s) to use the function. It shows `barplot(GNP ~ Year, data = longley)` which has the same syntax as some other R functions like `lm` and `plot`, where `y ~ x` means, depending on the function, "regress or plot y as a function of x."